# pam_userdb could not open database

Tags: linux, authentication, pam, vsftpd

In trying to set up vsftpd to use virtual users I hit this problem.

I created a database file:

```
db_load -T -t hash -f users.txt /etc/vsftpd/users.db
```

And `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`:

```
session optional pam_keyinit.so force revoke
auth    required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users.db
account required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users.db
```

But despite the database being readable by the `vsftpd` process, I end up with this in `/var/log/auth.log`

> pam_userdb(vsftpd:auth): user_lookup: could not open database `/etc/vsftpd/users.db': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `pam_userdb` silently adds `.db` to the path, so you need this config instead

```
session optional pam_keyinit.so force revoke
auth    required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users
account required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/users
```

This isn't mentioned in the man page, and in fact the example given incorrectly uses `/etc/dbtest.db` instead of `/etc/dbtest`.